# yii2 убрать в форме у имён полей префикс имени модели

Tags: php, yii2

Как убрать в форме у имён полей префикс имени модели. Сейчас поля такие (смотри ниже). У текстового поля значение атрибута `name="People[registration]"`. такие имена генерируются по-умолчанию. Как убрать префикс `People` (это имя модели).

```
<input type="text" id="people-registration" class="form-control" name="People[registration]" placeholder="Адрес регистрации">
```

Форму создаю так

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'id' => 'peoples_form',
    'action' => ['/site/add-new-people'],
]); ?>
<?= $form->field($peopleModel, 'registration')->textInput(['placeholder' => $peopleModel->getAttributeLabel('registration')])->label(false) ?>
<div class="form-group">
<?= Html::submitButton('Добавить', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
</div>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Comment: не использовать `$form` очевидно же. А чем это мешает-то?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский мне мешает тем, что я хочу использовать это - https://github.com/kflorence/jquery-deserialize. А модели при запросе на выборку данных возвращает мне данные без этого префикса модели. В итоге я не могу воспользоваться jquery-deserialize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно избавиться от префикса, если переопределить метод модели `formName` и передать аргументом пустую строку перед тем, как скармливать модель форме:

```
  Model::formName("");
```

[Источник](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#formName()-detail)

> The form name is mainly used by yii\widgets\ActiveForm to determine how to name the input fields for the attributes in a model. If the form name is "A" and an attribute name is "b", then the corresponding input name would be "A[b]". If the form name is an empty string, then the input name would be "b".